# How do I keep OPTION classes with Ext.form.ComboBox in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, html-select

When using Google's site translator widget, you have the option of putting a "notranslate" class on HTML elements that should be left untranslated. I've applied these to individual OPTION elements of a SELECT element where some of the options should be translated and others shouldn't, but when I call Ext.form.ComboBox(), the classes on individual OPTION elements are not carried over.

I need to make something like this:

```
<select>
    <option>Please choose your team:</option>
    <option class="notranslate">1983 Los Angeles Dodgers</option>
    <option class="notranslate">1983 Atlanta Braves</option>
<select>
```

get turned into this:

```
<!-- note the class "notranslate" -->
<div class="x-layer x-combo-list " id="..." style="...">
<div class="x-combo-list-inner" id="..." style="...">
    <div class="..."><font><font>Please choose your team:</font></font></div>
    <div class="... notranslate"><font><font>1983 Los Angeles Dodgers</font></font></div>
    <div class="... notranslate"><font><font>1983 Atlanta Braves</font></font></div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

**Updated with more information**
I am using version 3.4, and this is the code I currently have in place:

```
var teamChoice = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    typeAhead: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    transform: 'teamChoice',
    width: 300,
    forceSelection: true
});
```

I've seen the listClass option, but it seems to apply to all list items. In my scenario, I would like to apply the class only to the list items that already have the "notranslate" class on the original OPTION element.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for ExtJS 4?  I'm not sure how it varies for 3.3.1 but I believe this should work for you:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {

   ...

   listConfig: {
      itemCls: 'notranslate'
   }

   ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question for clarity (and my ExtJS version). It looks like your solution would apply the class to every list item, not just the ones that already had it in the original element, which isn't quite what I'm hoping to find.